# SDKMAN - Is it possible to download sdks manually for installation

Tags: sdkman

When I try to install an SDK (e.g. visualvm) using sdkman, download takes very long time (more than 1 hour). I was able to download zip directly from source much faster with tor browser.

Is it possible to configure sdkman to use local zip for installation instead of downloading the archive from source?

I've copied downloaded archive to `~/.sdkman/tmp` and `~/.sdkman/archives` folders. But when I try to install, sdkman tries to download the file again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to make it work by copying the downloaded archive to `~/.sdkman/tmp` folder and changing the name to what is expected by sdkman

**For visualvm:**

```
~/.sdkman/tmp$ cp /mnt/c/Users/user123/Downloads/visualvm_202.zip .
~/.sdkman/tmp$ mv visualvm_202.zip visualvm-2.0.2.bin
```

**For micronaut:**

```
~/.sdkman/tmp$ cp /mnt/c/Users/user123/Downloads/micronaut-1.3.5.zip .
~/.sdkman/tmp$ mv micronaut-1.3.5.zip micronaut-1.3.5.bin
```

**How to find the file name `sdkman` is expecting:**

- Try to install SDK usually with `sdk install visualvm 2.0.2`
- If downloading SDK is too slow, abort the installation process with `ctrl + c`
- `ls ~/.sdkman/tmp` and you can see the filename `sdkman` is trying to download

Please suggest if there is any simpler and better approach